# If $X\sim Bin(4,\frac{1}{2})$, find the distribution of $Y = (2X-4)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X\sim Bin(4,\frac{1}{2})$ be a random variable. Let $Y = (2X-4)^2$. Find  the density probability function of $Y$.

**My try:**

So 
$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\binom{4}{x}(\frac{1}{2})^x(\frac{1}{2})^{4-x} & x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $\alpha(x)= (2X-4)^2$

for the transformation $\quad y = 0, 4, 16$

So then $P(Y = y) = \sum_{x \in \alpha^{-1}(\{y\})}f_X(x)$

- $P(Y = 0) = \sum_{x \in \alpha^{-1}(\{0\})}f_X(x) = f_X(2)$
- $P(Y = 4) = \sum_{x \in \alpha^{-1}(\{4\})}f_X(x) = f_X(1) + f_X(3)$
- $P(Y = 16) = \sum_{x \in \alpha^{-1}(\{16\})}f_X(x) = f_X(0) + f_X(4)$

And finally 
$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
f_X(2) & y = 0, \\
f_X(1) + f_X(3) &  y = 4, \\
f_X(0) + f_X(4) & y = 16
\end{cases}
$$

I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Looks good. If you are learning this for the first time, perhaps you should also compute the remaining terms.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : Sorry to post it as an answer instead of commenting but I cannot comment yet.

It looks correct to me!